# Google maps reviews crawling with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm a beginner at crawling. I have a problem. this is my code and success in crawling but without "more".

this is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

# Specify the URL of the business page on Google Maps
url = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Henn+na+Hotel+Tokyo+Asakusa+Tawaramachi/@35.7081735,139.7865534,17z/data=!3m1!5s0x60188eb8e5155075:0x3c1d343c96398eb6!4m11!3m10!1s0x60188f36ab21f05b:0x9241dab287ff62c9!5m2!4m1!1i2!8m2!3d35.7081692!4d139.7914243!9m1!1b1!16s%2Fg%2F11h0gzlhht?hl=en&entry=ttu'

# Create an instance of the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

# Navigate to the specified URL
driver.get(url)

# Wait for the reviews to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)  # Increased the waiting time
# Scroll down to load more reviews
body = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'm6QErb') and contains(@class, 'DxyBCb') and contains(@class, 'kA9KIf') and contains(@class, 'dS8AEf')]")
num_reviews = len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wiI7pd'))
while True:
    body.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(2)  # Adjust the delay based on your internet speed and page loading time
    new_num_reviews = len(driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wiI7pd'))
    if new_num_reviews == num_reviews:
        # Scroll to the top to ensure all reviews are loaded
        body.send_keys(Keys.HOME)
        time.sleep(2)
        break
    num_reviews = new_num_reviews

# Wait for the reviews to load completely
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'wiI7pd')))

# Extract the text of each review
review_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'wiI7pd')
reviews = [element.text for element in review_elements]

# Print the reviews
print(reviews)

# Close the browser
driver.quit()
```

for example of result

```
"Thank you for staying at the Henn na Hotel Tokyo Asakusa-Tawaramachi. \nWe appreciate that you took the time 
to input your valuable feedback.\nWe are sorry that you were not satisfied with the breakfast. We will share your …
More',"
```

How can I get a all data? I mean want to get the data in "more" while scrolling down.

So I try fix problem myself

```
more = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ChdDSUhNMG9nS0VJQ0FnSUNsc29ITjJnRRAB"]/span[2]/button').click()
```

I got a more button's path and make a code but It dosen't work.

Thank you for reading and wait the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to be able to click on the "more" button in the review sections and extract the text of each of the reviews. due to there being multiple "more" buttons i would suggest creating a loop so it can take the data one review at a time then move onto the next and repeating the process while appending the data each time. To do this i would use the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
import multiprocessing
import time
import csv
from operator import itemgetter 

#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Imports
website = 'https://www.google.com/maps/place/Henn+na+Hotel+Tokyo+Asakusa+Tawaramachi/@35.7081692,139.7888494,17z/data=!4m22!1m12!3m11!1s0x60188f36ab21f05b:0x9241dab287ff62c9!2sHenn+na+Hotel+Tokyo+Asakusa+Tawaramachi!5m2!4m1!1i2!8m2!3d35.7081692!4d139.7914243!9m1!1b1!16s%2Fg%2F11h0gzlhht!3m8!1s0x60188f36ab21f05b:0x9241dab287ff62c9!5m2!4m1!1i2!8m2!3d35.7081692!4d139.7914243!16s%2Fg%2F11h0gzlhht?entry=ttu'
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') 
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(website)

#/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////set up

def accept_policy():
    try:
        accept_policy = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'button')
        for button in accept_policy:
            if button.text == "Accept all":
                print(button.text)
                button.click()
                break
    except TimeoutException:
            print("Cookie policy button not found or unable to click.")


accept_policy()

try:
    testing = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')))
    print(testing.text)
except TimeoutException:
    print("h1 element not found within the specified time.")

all_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
for button in all_buttons:
     if button.text == 'Reviews':
          print(button.text)
          button.click()
          break

time.sleep(5)
print("next")

def click_more_buttons():
    more_buttons = 0
    body_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'jftiEf')# Find buttons within the current 'jftiEf' element
    for body in body_elements: 
        buttons = body.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "w8nwRe")# Iterate over each button within the current 'jftiEf' element
        for button in buttons:
            if button.text == "More":# Check if the button text is "More"
                more_buttons += 1
                button.click()
            print(more_buttons)#this will tell us how many more buttons are currently loaded
            print(body.text)


click_more_buttons()
```

Hey here's an updated version of the code! this will now get all the data in the reviews section the only part you need to worry about is scrolling to the bottom to make it all visable. ive made it into a function so you can call it when you are ready to extractt he content.16/01/2024 - 00:50am

Comment: Thank you for your ask! but It still doesn't work I have two problems. First, your comment, create "more_buttons". What is the tag name?(By,Tag_name, 'button'). Sorry, this problem is due to my background in python.  And what line of my code should I put it in for it to work with scroll down? Maybe the "more" button in google maps review is not text I think.

Comment: Your welcome sorry i wrote that answer in work so i didnt have time to test it but to explain above this code works when i run it and clicks all the more buttons on the page. you can remove the print statements as they are just there to for my own testing of the solution. i hope this helps if not please let me know and i can take another look of course happy codeing! :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm late. 
I appreciate your comments and rewrite the code! that is so wonderful! You saved my code.
But I have some problems that are working with some parts review. I mean some click "more button", some don't.

I tried giving it more time or changing the order of the code to solve the problem. But, I failed. If you okay to give me an answer to this problem?

Comment: To explain the symptoms in detail, the "more" appeared as text in the original code's printed review. But now there is no "more", but it is displayed as "..." and hidden content is not crawled.

Comment: Hey sorry im only getting back now busy weekend and day! ive updated my code it will give you everything u need now :) only thing u need to do is load all the reviews like before and call the function when your ready to extract the data. :) if you have any more issues reach  out to me il keep an eye tomorrow in work!

Comment: Thank you so much! It is super worked. You saved my life! :)
Really I appreciate it

Comment: Your very welcome please let me know if you need anything else! If you could accept the answer for me i would really appreciate it too :) have a great day!